# Bypass notification sd card not support on android

Tags: android

sd card not support

I have a problem on android 11 when the memory card says not supported and asks to format it will lose data
is there any way to use shell to grant permission to sd card without losing data i have root permission

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.